# Javascript: Array of objects to object containing arrays of values - most performant way?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Desired: loop over a single array of objects, and construct multiple arrays for assigning to an object, based on the keys in those objects in most concise and performant manner. Two approaches:

One:

```
const arrayOfObjectsToObjectOfArraysOfValues = items => {
  const newArrayOne = []
  const newArrayTwo = []
  const newArrayThree = []

  items.forEach(({ value1, value2, value3 }) => {
    newArrayOne.push(value1)
    newArrayTwo.push(value2)
    newArrayThree.push(value3)
  })

  return { newArrayOne, newArrayTwo, newArrayThree }
}
```

Two:

```
const arrayOfObjectsToObjectOfArraysOfValues = items => ({
   newArrayOne: items.map(({ value1 }) => value1),
   newArrayTwo: items.map(({ value2 }) => value2),
   newArrayThree: items.map(({ value3 }) => value3),
})
```

Edit (There is also this option):

```
const arrayOfObjectsToObjectOfArraysOfValues = items => {
  return items.reduce((r, { value1, value2, value3 }, i) => {
    r.newArrayOne[i] = value1;
    r.newArrayTwo[i] = value2;
    r.newArrayThree[i] = value3;
    return r;
  }, { newArrayOne: [], newArrayTwo: [], newArrayThree: [] });
}
```

Obviously the second one is more concise, but it can be criticized for doing three loops where only one is required. On the other hand the first one is doing 3 operations per loop cycle. The key question option is "which (or is there another more elegant) option (which) is most performant?"

Comment: Why the question if you already know the answer? It is 1 loop vs 3 loops. And the most performant way is `for` loop.

Comment: I thought maybe `.push` could be an expensive operation (more operations per loop)...

Comment: You definitely need to measure performance with e.g. jsperf on your targeted javascript engine. There is no obvious answer regarding performance here, apart from what estus said with reference to functional style functions being slower than their iterative loop counterparts.

Comment: Nope, push is fast, all it does is `arr[arr.length] = ...`. And forEach and map belong to the same weight class. Do the math. But yes, it never hurts to play with jsperf to know your stuff better.

Comment: Thanks estus! I think I had read somewhere that push was fast on chrome, but not so much elsewhere, the below seems to verify that. Never actually took a moment to think of what push does, so appreciate the spelling it out for me:).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got on the jsperf bandwagon for my first time... looks like the answer here is it depends on the client:

https://jsperf.com/arrayofobjectstoobjectofarraysofvalues/1

On Firefox option 1 is 23% slower. (832,000 ops per second baseline)
On Chrome option 2 is 88% slower.  (248,000 ops per second baseline)
On Safari option 2 is 48% slower.  (158,000 ops per second baseline)

Edit: reduce option is 2% slower in Chrome & Safari, but 50% slower in Firefox.

So, probably yes, option 1 is better in most cases. A pity for conciseness... Also, go Firefox - so fast!

Finally, I suppose Option one can become a little conciser using reduce.